# Picture size: larger than screen

Tags: contacts

A contact has a custom file field named : Passport copy
Context : I add a picture (jpg file) in this file "passport copy" .
And I save the contact. Then when I click on the file, a pop up is opened with the passport copy This is good.
But if the jpg is a wide file, the pop up is all over the page and I can't resize it. The picture is larger than my screen...
So I would like to specify a size for this pop up like 250px/250px. But I don't know how

Is it clearer ?
Regards,
hashkey

Comment: What version of Civi?

Comment: Hello Coleman,It's CiviCRM 4.6.2. Regards, HashKey

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem of the popup going off the screen for images that are too wide, but I did find that the popup's titlebar got hidden behind the menu if the image was too tall.

I've opened [this pull-request](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6097) to make things work a bit better in that situation.

Comment: Hello Coleman, And if the titlebar is visible, the bottom bar to resize is not visible. It would be easier if I could attach a screenshot.Regards,HashKey

Comment: Yes please do attach a screenshot, but apply the patch from my pull-request first, it really does help.